# Python string slicing

Tags: python, list, indexing

The code:

```
count = 0
oldcount = 0
for char in inwords:
    if char == " ":
        anagramlist.append(inwords[oldcount, count])
        oldcount = count
        count = 0
    else:
        count += 1
```

the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Knowhaw/Desktop/Python Programs/Anagram solver/HTS anagram.py", line 14,        
in <module>
    anagramlist.append(inwords[oldcount, count])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

what the hell is going on?
count and oldcount are obviously ints, yet the error says they aren't

I can even write

```
anagramlist.append(inwords[int(oldcount), int(count)])
```

and get the same error

Comment: the strange title pulled me here...

Comment: I can see how the error message could be interpreted to imply that indexing with multiple integers is supported. "string index must be an integer" would be clearer. Just an observation...

Comment: @chepner: It surely looks confusing message for a beginner but the documentation [http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html] has enough clarity


`Like in Icon, substrings can be specified with the slice notation: two indices separated by a colon.

>>>


>>> word[4]

'A'

>>> word[0:2]

'He'

>>> word[2:4]

'lp'`

Comment: @chepner: and the message also suggests(if one doesn't know) that indexes have other uses too apart from accessing a single symbol in a string

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're trying to use `(oldcount, count)` as an index to the list. This is a tuple, not an int.

Do you perhaps mean:

```
anagramlist.append(inwords[oldcount:count])
```

?

Answer (score 4):

You have the slicing syntax wrong. The code:

```
inwords[oldcount, count]
```

is parsed the same as:

```
inwords[(oldcount, count)]
```

You're not slicing from `oldcount` to `count`, you're creating a tuple of `oldcount` and `count` and using that as a string index.

The correct Python slicing syntax would be:

```
inwords[oldcount:count]
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you just trying to do `anagramlist = inwords.split()` ?
If you really want to slice it manually, you'll have to use:

```
anagramlist.append(inwords[oldcount:count+oldcount])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code, you are probably trying to use the slice notation, which requires the use of `:`, not `,`. That comma makes the interpreter understand your code as using a tuple as index of a string, which is obviously not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I think something is wrong with `(inwords[oldcount, count])`. You cannot use `(oldcount, count)` as an index.